# How can I generate random numbers in Python?

Tags: python, random

Are there any built-in libraries in Python or Numpy to generate random numbers based on various common distributions, such as:

- Normal
- Poisson
- Exponential
- Bernoulli

And various others?

Are there any such libraries with multi-variate distributions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scipy.stats import bernoulli,poisson,norm,expon
```

bernoulli, poisson, norm, expon and many others are documented [here](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.stats.distributions.html)

```
print(norm.rvs(size=30))
print(bernoulli.rvs(.3,size=30))
print(poisson.rvs(1,2,size=30))
print(expon.rvs(5,size=30))
```

All the distributions defined in scipy.stats have a common interface to the pdf, cdf, rvs (random variates). More info [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:n7h6Kx32R54J:www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/scipy_guide_01.html#stats).

Comment: Import soul. Damn you Python !

Comment: Your second link there says "**Forbidden**" ... "You don't have permission to access /~dkuhlman/scipy_course_01.html on this server." --- looks like linkrot

Comment: @Glen_b: I've changed the link to a cached version of the page.

Answer (score 5):

The [`random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) module has tons of functions for generating random numbers in lots of way.  Not sure it has multi-variate.

[Numpy.random](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) would be the next place to look.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding in a link to the documentation for `random`