# How to have random items of different rarity in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm making a code in which there is suppose, a box, and when you open the box you will either get a weapon that is common, uncommon, rare or legendary. But the problem is all the weapons have the same chance of occurring so how do I change the code so that it's more difficult for rarer weapons to spawn?

Answer (score 3):

**python 3.x:**

You can use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) and supply a distribution for the randomness:

```
import random

things = ["common","rare","epic"]
chance = [90,9,1]

results = random.choices(things,chance,k=1000)

from collections import Counter
print(Counter(results))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'common': 921, 'rare': 75, 'epic': 4})
```

Distributions can be absolute or cumulative - absolute ones are internally converted into cumulativ ones. See the [doku](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)

I use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the resulting 1000 random draws.

---

**python 2.x:**

You can create a list with the correct amount of things in it and draw via `random.choice` in a loop (no random.choices for you, sorry):

```
things = ["common"]*90 + ["rare"]*9 + ["epic"]

thing = random.choice(things)  # only 1 item - loop if need more
```

---

There are several not-quite dupes for this:

- [Python Random choice with 'percentage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813308/python-random-choice-with-percentage)
- [Generate random numbers with a given (numerical) distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution)
- [How can I generate random numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655559/how-can-i-generate-random-numbers-in-python) (some specific distributions)

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can help you with that, the p value is the probability and the sum must be 1.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(('common', 'uncommon', 'rare' , 'legendary'), p=[0.4, 0.35, 0.2, 0.05])
```

In the example I added Counter to show the occurrence of each item.

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

item = []
for _ in range(1,100):
    item.append(np.random.choice(('common', 'uncommon', 'rare' , 'legendary'), p=[0.4, 0.35, 0.2, 0.05]))

print(Counter(item))
```

Comment: [numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) ... why not simply give a size of 100 ?

Comment: @Patrick. You're right, for the example even shorter.